# Prometheus intrumentation for distributed accumulated batch jobs

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I run a build script multiple times per day. My feeling is that me and my colleagues spend a considerable amount of time waiting for this script to execute. Now I want to know: **how much time do we spend per day waiting for the script to execute?**. I can be satisfied with an over all average, even though I would really like to have day-by-day data (e.g. "last Monday we spent X minutes waiting for the script to execute, on Tuesday...)

To find the answer, I spun up Prometheus with a push gateway. In the build script, I added a REST call  to the push gateway that posts metrics (type: `counter`) labeled with machine name and sample data the elapsed time to execute the script.

Data is being collected, but I realize that the data I gather isn't enough to answer my question, I would need the metrics I push (that is: the current runs elapsed time) to be accumulated to previous data. [Looking at the documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md#non-goals), I get the feeling that this will not be supported through the push gateway:

> The Pushgateway is explicitly not an aggregator or distributed counter but rather a metrics cache

My questions are:

- Is it possible to collect the metrics I want through Prometheus Push Gateway. If not, what are my options?
- If it is possible, what metrics should I collect how?

Comment: Do you mean grouping the metrics before getting scraped by prometheus ? push gateway supports grouping keys, please have a look at README of https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway

Answer (score 1):

In general, Pushgateway is indeed *not a distributed counter*, but...

The right way to look at Pushgateway, imho, is like "yet another scraping endpoint".
This means, that it **will not aggregate** the metrics you pushing, and will just hold them "as-is".
But you actually do not need it to be aggregated - Prometheus will **scrape** the data from PushGateway, and all your data will be available in the Prometheus.

After that - you can run any queries you want over Prometheus - using PromQL directly from Prometheus, or leveraging Grafana.

**Note**: There are several discussions about Pushgateway, and using it have its downside. There is general [guideline "non-goals" recommendation](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#non-goals) to use Pushgateway as the "**last option**" - the recommendation is to expose /metrics route instead, even in jobs.

P.S. If you believe you really need the Aggregated metrics, you can take a look at [Weavework's aggregation gateway](https://github.com/weaveworks/prom-aggregation-gateway), mentioned in the same article. But once again - I think it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I need a push gateway to accept a counter type as well.  Can I use push-gateway for a counter? If so, how? If not, what can I use? Thanks